# How works inject img tag on DOM manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm manually injecting an  tag into the DOM, however I need to check if it was loaded before taking any action with this component in the DOM. Why does this occur?

```
let img = $("<img />").attr({
    src: 'path to img',
    name: 'name of img'
});

$("#myDIV").html(img);

$(img).one('load', function(){
    // why can i do action with 'img' only after being available in the DOM?
});
```

Comment: Image loading is asynchronous.

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do with the component. If you want to get the size, you have to wait for the image to load. If you want to change its CSS, you don't have to wait.

Comment: To rule out timing issues, bind the load handler to the image **before** you attach it to the DOM

Comment: @Taplar that and the other issue may be that html accept string according to jQuery docs http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: @jcubic https://jsfiddle.net/1632hojp/  that's not an issue

Comment: https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=git&fn=jQuery.fn.html  `html()` actually tests the type of the argument to see if it is a string or not.  If it is not a string, it will simply append it to the element.

Comment: @Taplar what is the difference between bind before or after attach element to the DOM?